# Why isn't my refrigerator water line delivering water?

Tags: plumbing

Bought a new fridge two days ago. Need to hook up water line for ice and water. No water is coming through the copper piping when the valve is turned on. Old fridge water quit working in the door - thought the line was frozen or filter was bad but ice maker made ice.

Comment: Really there is no need to use all caps.  That's bad etiquette here and elsewhere.  It's not clear from your question what you're having trouble with.  I gather than you are having issues with the water hookup.  First of all, does the water flow with nothing hooked up to the line when you open the valve?  Next, does water flow when you just hook up the water line?

Comment: Show a photo of the valve, please.

Answer (score 3):

Chances are you have a cheap saddle valve. Plumbers and appliance installers often use them because they're quick. They use a piercing needle built into them to punch a hole in copper pipes. The problem is that they're prone to corroding shut over time. Also, they have poor flow rates.

[image]

You can simply close the old one and install a new one if you like, but evenutally it'll crud shut also, as the second one in my current home did.

The right solution is to install a proper valve. This requires cutting pipe, but isn't terribly difficult. The benefits are longevity and flow, which is important when you have a drinking water dispenser and not just an ice maker.

[image]

Comment: "...but ice maker made ice."  If his ice maker is making ice, that can't be the issue because the water for the ice maker comes from the same place.

Comment: @J.Raefield, that was the old fridge with the working ice... maybe.  Question needs cleanup and more details.

Comment: As I hinted, an ice maker can function with very low flow. The water dispenser wouldn't so much. I'm guessing here.

Answer (score 1):

**If your ice maker is truly working but the door water is not**, then it has to be a problem inside of the refrigerator water lines or a problem with the electrical signal triggering the valve for the water dispenser. Since it is a new fridge, I would call the supplier to come take a look at it under warranty.

Comment: unless the ice maker needs less pressure than the water dispenser. it's async and will wait a long time to fill, so that's a possibility.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose too it depends on the definition of "not working", i.e. it is dribbling out slowly, ergo it is not working RIGHT.